# shrink_to_fit() vs swap trick

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, time-complexity, big-o

I have a game where certain game objects spawn all at once and then despawn as they get destroyed/killed. The game objects are elements in an `std::vector`, and I'd like to minimize memory usage. I'm used to the swap trick,

```
std::vector<gameObject>(gameObjectVector.begin(), gameObjectVector.end()).swap(gameObjectVector);
```

but I noticed the inbuilt `shrink_to_fit()` from C++11. However, it has linear complexity while the swap trick is constant. Isn't the swap trick superior in every way?

Comment: `std::vector<gameObject>(gameObjectVector.begin(), gameObjectVector.end())` you think this doesn't have linear complexity?

Comment: Consider also the use of `std::deque` since most (all?) implementations internally use a linked list of chunks so you won't have to allocate a big chunk as when using a `vector`.

Comment: Your code copies all the objects every time...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The swap trick isn't actually constant-time. The cost of performing the actual swap is indeed O(1), but then there's the cost of the `std::vector` destructor firing and cleaning up all the allocated space. That can potentially have cost Ω(n) if the underlying objects have nontrivial destructors, since the `std::vector` needs to go and invoke those destructors. There's also the cost of invoking the copy constructors for all the elements stored in the initial vector, which is similarly Ω(n).

As a result, both approaches should have roughly the same complexity, except that `shrink_to_fit` more clearly telegraphs the intention and is probably more amenable to compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 5):

Accepted answer that also got featured on isocpp.org is wrong.

`shrink_to_fit` is **[nonbinding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit)** requirement. 
I personally I think it is idiotic from ISO to leave this as nonbiding(without providing some stronger guarantees about what happens) since it is confusing, but maybe they had good reasons(tm).

Comment: Possibly non-binding because of memory allocation issues. e.g. what should happen for a vector of 1 char? Is it possible to reduce capacity to 1 byte?

Comment: I think the constructor is also non-binding on `capacity`, although I haven’t checked the standard to be sure. It would have to be if the iterators given weren’t random-access, and although there is reason to overload it in the implementation, I doubt the standard requires that.

Comment: It is quite reasonable that shrink_to_fit is non-binding. The reason for it being so is that there might be situations where the vector already has an ideal size and thus can't be shrunk even if it has extra capacity. Imagine for instance that all allocations bigger than 1MB has to be in 4K chunks. A vector with size 1MB + 1 will have a capacity of 4K - 1, yet shrink_to_fit will not reduce its capacity.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but doesn't the swap trick have the same weakness? I don't believe the range constructor makes any capacity guarantees either.