# The different of swap and shrink_to_fit() for std::vector

Tags: c++, vector

As we know, `swap()` can release the memory of vector, but `shrink_to_fit()` can do it too. is it right?

```
vector<int> nums; 
nums.push_back(1);
nums.push_back(1);
nums.push_back(2);
nums.push_back(2); 

vector<int>().swap(nums);
vector<int>().shrink_to_fit();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [shrink\_to\_fit() vs swap trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667175/shrink-to-fit-vs-swap-trick)

Comment: `vector<int>().shrink_to_fit();` creates a new empty unnamed `vector` object, shrinks it (which is a no op) and then destroys the object.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> vector<int>().swap(nums);
> ```

This is practically equivalent to (although not guaranteed to be so)

```
nums.clear();
nums.shrink_to_fit();
```

I recommend writing the latter since it is clearer to read. The swap trick was used prior to introduction of shrink_to_fit.

> swap() can release the memory of vector,

Swap itself won't release memory. It is the destructor of the temporary object that releases memory.

> ```
> vector<int>().shrink_to_fit(nums);
> ```

This is ill formed.

> ```
> vector<int>().shrink_to_fit();
> ```

This modifies only a temporary object and has no other side-effects, so this is practically equivalent to an empty statement assuming it is optimised out.

Comment: thanks! I have modified the code.

Comment: @王先冬 I've updated to correspond the modified question.